# When i use cout.tie(NULL), program doesn't print anything for my code, but if i print endl, program works fine

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void scan_a_line_indefinitely()
{
    // scan line indefinitely
    string input_line;
    while(getline(cin,input_line)) 
    {
        cout << input_line ; **// doesn't print if i use this line**
        //cout << input_line << endl; **// if i use this line, it works fine**
    }

}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);
    scan_a_line_indefinitely();
    return 0;
}
```

someone please help me understand the problem with this code.
i think the problem is with cout.tie() and cout.tie(), when i remove these, program works fine.

Comment: Yes, you should remove those, unless you have a good reason to put them in.

Comment: As said below, `std::cout << std::endl` is equivalent to `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush`. Aside from that, if you have a new question, ask as a new question. Also, [don't use `using namespace std;`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::cout` will flush under these conditions:

1. An input-stream which is tied to `std::cout` tries to read input.
   You removed the ties.
2. iostreams are synchronized with stdio, thus effectively unbuffered.
   You disabled the synchronization.
3. The buffer is full.
   That takes a bit longer.
4. The program ends normally.
   That comes too late for you.
5. There is a manual flush (`stream.flush()` which is called when streaming `std::flush`; `stream << std::endl` is equivalent to `stream << stream.widen('\n') << std::flush`).
   You have none of those.

So, fix any of them and you will see your output earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If only iostreams are used you can add a manual flush to the output :

```
std::cout.flush();
```

Or

```
std::cout << /* the output */<< std::flush;
```

Also:

`std::cout << std::endl` is equivalent to `std::cout << '\n' << std::flush`